# how can i use array_filter in php

Tags: php, arrays, filter, array-filter

hi i have this question

```
my array

[
  [
    'mykey'=>40
  ],
  [
    'mykey'=>37
  ],
  [
    'mykey'=>14
  ],
  [
    'mykey'=>7
  ],
]
```

i have an array and i wanna filter some key by a value so use this

```
$r = array_filter($res, function($e){
            return $e['mykey'] == 37;
        });
```

but i need to campare an array of numbers something like this

```
$r = array_filter($res, function($e){
            return $e['mykey'] == [37, 14, 7];
        });
```

how i can filter like this so if mykey is equal to those values so return the arrays with the values 37 14 and 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the value exists in a list.

```
<?php
...

$r = array_filter($res, function($e){
    return in_array($e['mykey'], [37, 14, 7]);
});
```